# How to setup a keybinding in ZSH to resolve and edit the last command registered in the history?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

**Given:**

I've just run the script

```
$ my-script.sh
```

which lives in `~/bin` and is a symlink to the real file

```
$ ls -l ~/bin
[...] /Users/myself/bin/my-script.sh -> /Users/myself/.config/scripts/real-name.sh
```

**Then:**

I'd like to edit the file pointed at by the script I just invoked with.

Something like:

```
${EDITOR} "$(readlink $(which my-script.sh))"
```

I have tried to load the following function, which

```
function edit-last() {
    LAST_COMMAND="$(history -1 | sed -Ee 's/^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*//')"
    REAL_PATH="$(readlink $(which "${LAST_COMMAND}"))"
    $EDITOR  "${REAL_PATH}"
}
```

I loaded the function and I invoked it explicitly after running my script and it almost worked.

The 2 main issues I got are:

1. I have set `EDITOR="emacsclient -n -a '' -c"`, but invoking it via `$EDITOR` doesn't work when expanded. I'm getting `command not found: emacsclient -c -a '' -t`. If I change the last line to `emacsclient -c -a '' -t "${REAL_PATH}"`. It works.
2. I've tried `bindkey "^e" edit-last` but when I type "CTRL-e" I get `No such widget 'edit-last'`.

I'm using ZSH with `oh-my-zsh`.

How can I fix that? Is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but on zsh we can do:

```
${EDITOR} =script
```

With equal sign (in my case even TAB works) zsh will open the file associated with the name "script".

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. `=script` is definitely an improvement to typing `\`which script\``.